# GET запрос в node.js не возвращает ни error, ни body

Tags: node.js, get, request, vps

GET запрос на сервере node.js, например:

```
request('https://www.google.ru/', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Не возвращает ни error, ни body, а response выдает такой:

```
"_readableState": {
    "objectMode": false,
    "highWaterMark": 16384,
    "buffer": {
        "head": null,
        "tail": null,
        "length": 0
    },
    "length": 0,
    "pipes": null,
    "pipesCount": 0,
    "flowing": null,
    "ended": false,
    "endEmitted": false,
    "reading": false,
    "sync": true,
    "needReadable": false,
    "emittedReadable": false,
    "readableListening": false,
    "resumeScheduled": false,
    "destroyed": false,
    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
    "awaitDrain": 0,
    "readingMore": true,
    "decoder": null,
    "encoding": null
},
"readable": true,
"domain": null,
"_events": {
    "end": "[Unknown]"
},
"_eventsCount": "[Unknown]",
"_maxListeners": "[Unknown]",
"socket": "[Unknown]",
"connection": "[Unknown]",
"httpVersionMajor": "[Unknown]",
"httpVersionMinor": "[Unknown]",
"httpVersion": "[Unknown]",
"complete": "[Unknown]",
"headers": "[Unknown]",
"rawHeaders": "[Unknown]",
"trailers": "[Unknown]",
"rawTrailers": "[Unknown]",
"upgrade": "[Unknown]",
"url": "[Unknown]",
"method": "[Unknown]",
"statusCode": "[Unknown]",
"statusMessage": "[Unknown]",
"client": "[Unknown]",
"_consuming": "[Unknown]",
"_dumped": "[Unknown]",
"req": "[Unknown]"
}
```

Проблема появилась недавно, до этого точно такой же скрипт на VPS (centos 7) работал нормально и точно такой же скрипт сейчас нормально работает на Windows 10, т.е. проблема возникает только при запуске скрипта на сервере.

Comment: Версия node.js везде одинаковая? На этом VPS выход в сеть внешнюю есть вообще? Что выдаёт `curl -v https://www.google.ru/` в консоли?

Comment: Версия node.js одинаковая на VPS и на Win 10

Comment: Curl выдает статус 200. Странное что-то происходит, такая проблема появляется через раз при запросе на любые url